# calling custom function in django model

Tags: django, django-models

i have a generate(variable) function in another file, i want to call it in my models.py file.
here is my code.

```
class Season(models.Model):
    Year = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=getyear())
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    league = models.ManyToManyField(League)
    fixgen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_progress = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Year

    def createfixtures(self):
        generate(self)
```

but when i run the file, it gives me the following error.

```
Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function inner_run at 0xa05eae4>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
   models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/yousuf/PycharmProjects/CricketManager/../CricketManager/Cricket/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Cricket.fixtures import generate
  File "/home/yousuf/PycharmProjects/CricketManager/Cricket/fixtures.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Cricket.models import League, Season, Team, Fixture
  File "/home/yousuf/PycharmProjects/CricketManager/Cricket/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Cricket.fixtures import generate
ImportError: cannot import name generate
```

can i import a function that works fine if i call it from django shell. now i want to have it as part of django admin menu.

if somebody can look at it, and see what the problem is, or what is the work around for it.

//yousuf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a circular import between Cricket.models and Cricket.fixtures.  You will need to move common definitions out into a third module to break the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your project structure it's hard to say exactly why the import fails. However, most normally, the "fixtures" directory of an app just contains JSON/XML/whatever files and is therefore not treated as a module (by having an `__init__.py` file inside).

If there is not an `__init__.py` file in that directory, the directory is not a python module, and, therefore can't be imported. The simplest solution would be to obviously just add this file (it can be empty; it just needs to exist). However, because of what I stated above, putting python code in a directory name "fixtures" is a bad idea. It breaks convention for what that directory name is most commonly used for and thus becomes a point of confusion to other developers.